# Independent samples design where groups are statistically different at baseline

Tags: regression, median

I have a dataset wherein 2 independent groups received either treatment or placebo using the following 5-session design:

Session 1: Baseline (no treatment for either group)

Session 2: GroupA=treatment GroupB=Placebo

Session 3: GroupA=Treatment GroupB=Placebo

Session 4: GroupA=Treatment GroupB=Placebo

Session 5: Follow-up (no treatment for either group)

Measurement = Performance on a cognitive task (Time to navigate a virtual maze)

N=32 (16 subjects per group)

The trick is, when comparing groups at BASELINE ONLY, I found statistical differences between groups, where the Treatment Group already performs better than the Placebo Group, before any treatment was administered.

In order to solve this, I created difference scores where:

Improvement at Session N =  Performance at Session N - Performance at Baseline

With that, I did not find significant improvements between groups, however, using the median split I see a significant improvement in the bottom 50% of performers from Baseline to Follow-Up in the Treatment Group whereas this was not found in the Placebo group. However I'm worried about the effects of regression to the mean.

My question is, is there a more valid way to analyze this data, that would allow me to show a difference in improvement between groups, based on their baseline performance?  From what I understand, regression analysis usually assumes equal performance at baseline, but my data does not satisfy this assumption. 
Thanks!